# LINQ to SQL and null values

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, exception, null

I have the following LINQ to SQL query:

```
var inTransitStocks = orderHistories.Where(oh => oh.Shipped_Qty > 0)
                                    .Select(oh => oh.Shipped_Qty); //.ToList();
var inTransitStock = (int)inTransitStocks.Sum();
```

Without the `ToList` call I get the exception below on the `Sum()` line:

> The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.Double which is a non-nullable value type.

If I add a `.ToList()` before sum (as shown in the comment) I don't get the error.

**Why do I get the error in the first place?** (`Shipped_Qty` is not null and no null data in that field exists in the db)

**Why is adding `ToList()` a fix?**

---

The sql query executed is below (there is more to the query than above):

```
SELECT [t0].[Shipped Qty]
FROM [dbo].[Order History] AS [t0]
WHERE ([t0].[Shipped Qty] > @p0) AND ([t0].[CUST_ID] = @p1) AND ([t0].[SHIP_TO_ID] = @p2) AND ([t0].[Item] = @p3) AND (([t0].[DT_LST_SHP] >= @p4) OR (UNICODE([t0].[LN_STA]) = @p5))
```

**No results are returned.**

Comment: This was asked many times ago, there was nothing to sum. Rewrite as `inTransitStocks.Sum(x => (int?)x) ?? 0` and it should work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is the following:

Without `ToList` the following query gets executed against the database:

```
select SUM(Shipped_Qty) from orderHistories where Shipped_Qty > 0;
```

If there are no rows matching this criteria, the result of this query is not 0 but `NULL`.

With `ToList` the following query gets executed:

```
select Shipped_Qty from orderHistories where Shipped_Qty > 0;
```

The result (no rows) will be put into a list. The result is an empty list. On that empty list you execute the LINQ to Objects extension method `Sum`. The sum of an empty list is 0 and NOT `null`.

So basically: Different semantics lead to different results.

Comment: That's what I wasn't getting, I expected no results to not return `NULL`, as `NULL` could be something legitimately returned.

Comment: In SQL, SUM returns NULL in only two circumstances: (1) No rows to sum or (2) at least one of the rows to SUM is NULL.

Comment: Thanks, that's the key bit I didn't get, I was expecting no rows when summing no rows, not a null value.

Answer (score 0):

After you do the `ToList()` you are using the Linq-To-Objects implementation of `Sum`.

Before you do `ToList()` the `Sum` operation is being aggregated into the Linq-To-Sql query.

---

To find out why the Linq-To-Sql fails, follow [Daniel Hilgath's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12276558/659190).

Answer (score 0):

all was said but let me reformulate : this is because of the magic of var!

```
Without ToList() var <=> DbQuery
With ToList() var <=> List<Double>
```

The Sum function does not have the same behaviour on the two types...